# Setting Environment Variables on Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, environment-variables

I'm new to using Mac OS X. From my understanding, it uses Linux under the covers. I have a need to add an environment variable. Currently, whenever I start a terminal window, I've been executing `export MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=enabled`. I would like to automatically do this, system wide, when the machine starts.

How do I do that on Mac OS X? I tried adding the above line to `~/.bashrc` via nano without any luck. How should I set this environment variable?

Thank you!

Comment: BSD, not Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To affect system-wide settings, you probably should add:

`export MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=enabled`

to `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc` (the latter is sourced from `/etc/profile`).

OSX uses bash by default for its `/bin/sh`.  However, it does not use "Linux under the covers", but rather is mostly BSD (with some exceptions such as bash).

Here are some related questions/discussion (which suggest OSX-specific places to modify instead, e.g., `environment.plist`):

- [Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)
- [How do I set environment variables on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-on-os-x)
- [How to set system-wide environment variables on OS X Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107787/how-to-set-system-wide-environment-variables-on-os-x-mavericks)

Comment: What do you mean by 'modify /etc/bashrc'.  What to put there in modifications??

Comment: @igor You add `export MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=enabled` to `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`